# Excel changed my format numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

When I insert a txt file with numbers such as 185567.21 the result is 185.567.21. It keeps disturbing my numbers and I cannot work.

Any solutions to stop this?

Comment: Are they truly numbers? Or just strings resembling numbers?

Comment: Control Panel > Region and Language > Formats > Advanced. Change Digit Grouping to `123456789`

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your time to address to my problem. There are coordinates where the txt file contains easting northing . When i insert them in notepad it is ok but when I insert them in excel the numbers from 205567.89 changes to 205.567.89

Comment: Excel is seeing the values as a number, and changing it to Excel's default number format (varies depending on your Windows regional settings).  To retain the original format, you can import the values as Text.  If the text file has a file extension of `.txt`, then the `text import wizard` should open when you open the file, and you can designate that column as text. If that is not happening, you may need to "reset" the wizard.   If it is `.csv`, you will need a different process.

Comment: It is impossible for "205.567.89" to be a number. You can not have a dot being at the same time decimal separator and thousands separator. Hence my first comment. Check if there are any comma.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default formatting for Number fields will sort this out.

For temporary solution, highlight, format and change the numbers format.
For a permanent solution, you will need to look in settings to ignore decimal markers for 1000s

Comment: Hi HoNoR, Thank you for taking time to address. When I do change the default formatting for number fields then the 185.567.21 becomes 18556721. That means I loose the 2 decimals. The number should be 185567.21.

Comment: Is the 'Use 1000 seperator' box ticked? 

If all else fails, format the row/column as text and it will copy in as is.